# (iphone) Is CGImageRef NSObject ? c pointer?

Tags: iphone, types, cgimage

I'd like to pass CGImageRef variable to performSelectorOnMainThread
wrapping it inside NSValue with valueWithPointer is adequate here?

What's the type of CGImageRef?
Is it a typedef of c pointer?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CGImageRef` is a pointer to `CGImage` c-struct. For your case just casting it to id type must suffice:

```
[obj performSelectorOnMainThread:someSEL withObject:(id)cgImageRef];
```

Comment: Thanks, wouldn't performSelectorOnMainThread retain the object? I feared performSelector retaining c pointer, which wouldn't make sense. ?

Comment: I can't find a reference to that now, but if I remember correctly CG types are retainable as well as normal obj-c types - [(id)cgImageRef retain] may be valid code... And you can put CGImages in NSArray (may be useful if you want to do CAAnimation for layer contents)

Comment: Anyway - that memory management is handled by system and object will be released (or autoreleased) when selector gets called, so if it works then memory management is not you problem

Comment: do you think NSValue valueWithPointer/pointerValue approach is fine as well?

Comment: yes, that approach is also fine imo. it may be clearer as you see that you actually pass obj-c type to method